# Php api via array

Tags: php, arrays, api

Am trying to read a script api which returns an array:

```
$api_key = "Uez4TWYH6OAQQHoUcICWJ8UUFYmwQ";
$file_id = "LNzcOp2b1352047884";
$ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://ads.ngsms.tk/api/info.php?api_key='.$api_key.'&file_id='.$file_id); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$api = curl_exec($ch); $api = print_r($api); 
Echo $api['file_id'];
```

The above displays:

```
Array ( 
   [file_id] => LNzcOp2b1352047884 
   [file_name] => sic_ftp_3rda.sisx 
   [file_type] => application/octet-stream 
   [file_size] => 65144
)
```

How can I get the file_name and other values?

Comment: $api["file_name"]... but im seeing some more problems with your script. you are overriding the $api variable.. why?

Comment: its not workin.. Its diplay 'A'

Comment: @Lordcash have you tried the full code part of my answer?

Comment: @Lordcash The last block of code on the answer copy and paste it all and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get any value within the array reference it in the same way you have done for file_id but instead replace the key with the value you are after e.g:

```
$api['file_id'];
$api['file_name'];
$api['file_type'];
$api['file_size'];
```

Then to simply show this on the page, you can use echo:

```
echo    $api['file_id'];
echo    $api['file_name'];
echo    $api['file_type'];
echo    $api['file_size'];
```

So your full code would be:

```
    <?php
$api_key = "Uez4TWYH6OAQQHoUcICWJ8UUFYmwQ";
$file_id = "LNzcOp2b1352047884";
$ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://ads.ngsms.tk/api/info.php?api_key='.$api_key.'&file_id='.$file_id); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$api = curl_exec($ch); 
//print_r($api);
$fileid = get_string_between($api, "[file_id] => ", "[file_name] ");
$filename = get_string_between($api, " [file_name] => ", " [file_type] => ");
$filetype = get_string_between($api, " [file_type] => ", " [file_size] =>");
$filesize = get_string_between($api, " [file_size] => ", ")");
echo "ID: $fileid <br /> name: $filename <br />type: $filetype   <br /> size: " .$filesize;
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

Comment: it displayed Filename: A, pls if you have php installed on your system, pls try it out and help me.. The api_key and file_id is working

Comment: @Lordcash I've narrowed it down, to the fact that inside $api is not actually an array, but a string of an array, which is why it is not being parsed, but give me a sec and I will get a solution.

Comment: @Lordcash most eloquent way I could think of but it works see edit

Comment: ok letme try it. But i wrote the api my self, and am sure i return printed array, any ideas on where i went wrong in the info.php

Comment: it worked thanks, buh can you tell me how i would make the code in d api print out array i.e correct the error? Because i wrote them both, and i am testing them before realeasing the script

Comment: @lordcash sure thing post the code for it as a new question as this is getting messy and I will look at it when I wake up in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution just popping to my mind would be the exact same one already being the last command.

```
echo $api['file_name'] // to print it
$file_name = $api['file_name'];
```

Remove the `$api =` from before the `print_r`.